# Entity Framework Core skip and take from the back?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, postgresql-9.5

I have the following query:

```
IQueryable<SellerProductDTO> result = _dbContext.Products
            .Where(product => EF.Property<Guid?>(product, "SellerId") != null && EF.Property<Guid?>(product, "SellerId") == sellerId
                    && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phrase) ? product.SearchVector.Matches(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("english", phrase)) : true))
            .OrderByDescending(td => td.SearchVector.Rank(EF.Functions.ToTsQuery("english", phrase)));

List<Product> products = await result.Skip(page * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToListAsync();
```

I would like to optimize it so that if the result is big and the client provides small page size for pagination, navigating from 1st to the last page should not take a long time. I am thiking if the page that the client requests crosses the half point, skip and take from the back instead. How could I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: There should not really be a performance difference getting the first or last page. At least if we ignore any caching. Performance typically has more to do with indices and the number of records that need to be processed and returned. So your question does not make much sense to me.

Comment: Look at [Pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/pagination).

Comment: You're already using pagination. The problem with this though is that retrieving the next page of data requires running the query again and skipping over the first N results.  You can avoid this by retrieving the PKs of the results only, split them in pages and load only the records in a single page batch each time. This way you get the full count from the start and can decide how big the pages should be and which page to load

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use distributed redis cache with sliding expiration

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Answer (score 0):

You've basically got 2 choices

**Choice 1**

Pretty much all inbuilt text searches with (seemingly) any database suck in terms of speed. Your basically having to query the whole table - rank all the records and then order the records and return.

In the past I've used http://sphinxsearch.com/ to create an index and then you query that (with page/amount etc), get some ids for the rows you want and that's the way to create a truely killer search.

**Choice 2**

This is a bit more hacky, but basically once the search is done store the details and the results of the search (the list of ids should suffice) and then utilise that for the session to get the desired results for the user.

If you just did select the ids and store ... maybe in a session or maybe in a database that might just work. I've not done this before, and Choice 1 is probably the industry standard.